# When stating a transaction using sequelize, how to achieve some statements are out of transaction?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When stating a transaction, how to achieve some statements is out of transaction.

See the following example, the first `create` statement didn't get `transaction` option, so it should be out of transaction, and when rolling back it should be in database. However, both are in transaction and both rolled back. Any comments?

```
    describe.only('sequelzie transaction test', () => {
        const sequelize = new Sequelize('test', null, null, {
            dialect: 'sqlite',
    })

    const UserModel = sequelize.define('user', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
    })
    beforeEach (async () => {
        await sequelize.sync({force: true})
    })


    it('partial rollback transaction should work', async () => {
        const transaction  = await sequelize.transaction()
        try {
            await UserModel.create({name: 'ron'} )
            await UserModel.create({name: 'ron', {transaction}})
            await transaction.commit()
        }
        catch (e) {
            await transaction.rollback()
        }

        const users = await UserModel.findAll()
        expect(users).to.have.length(1) // failed here, it was 0, both are rolled back
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem i did find out in your code was that transaction was passed incorrectly in create function

```
await UserModel.create({name: 'ron'}, {transaction})
```

Transaction is part of options object. Also try enabling the debug option to check what queries are being executed. You will be able to discern the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time, actually I confirmed it is because it is for sqlite3, if it for postgre, all good.